# Chmod for application via script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

Im creating a script file and I want to add the permission via chmod -R 777 myApp/*

I add to the script the following line

```
cd /home/abc/aa_tmp  chmod -R 777 myApp/*
```

which doesnt work , when I try to update/edit file I got permission denied, any idea what I miss here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this;

```
#!/bin/bash
chmod -R 777 /home/abc/aa_tmp/myApp/*
```

if the user has enough privileges above script works. But if permissions is as below, throw permission denied

```
user@host:/tmp/$ ls -arlt
..
d---------  2 user user  4096 Aug 25 16:38 myApp
..
```

Answer (score 0):

Either you are not root, or the user does not own myApp. 
and you don't need the *, since it goes recursively.

- #su
- #chmod -R 777 myApp/